# Finding all divisors of an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem is to find all divisors of a given integer `n`.

(It may be better to implement a true prime generator, rather than a fixed set, [as discussed with examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2211990/1085805), but that was not my immediate concern. Also, I am aware that there are much faster algorithms to generate fixed number of prime numbers—I am avoiding them until I fully understand the algorithm.)

```
import functools
import itertools
import operator


def prime_generator(n):
    """
    Sieve of Eratosthenes
    Create a candidate list within which non-primes will be
    marked as None.
    """    
    cand = [i for i in range(3, n + 1, 2)]
    end = int(n ** 0.5) // 2

    # Loop over candidates (cand), marking out each multiple.
    for i in range(end):
        if cand[i]:
            cand[cand[i] + i::cand[i]] = [None] * (
                (n // cand[i]) - (n // (2 * cand[i])) - 1)

    # Filter out non-primes and return the list.
    return [2] + [i for i in cand if i]


primes_list = prime_generator(100000)


def factorize(n):
    prime_multiples = []
    for item in primes_list:
        if item > n:
            break
        else:
            while n > 1:
                if n % item == 0:
                    n //= item
                    prime_multiples.append(item)
                else:
                    break
    return prime_multiples


def calculate_divisors(n):
    prime_multiples_list = factorize(n)

    """
    construct unique combinations
    A, B, B, C --> A, B, C, AB, AC, BB, BC, ABC, ABB, BBC
    """
    unique_combinations = set()
    for i in range(1, len(prime_multiples_list)):
        unique_combinations.update(
            set(itertools.combinations(prime_multiples_list, i)))

    # multiply elements of each unique combination
    combination_product = list(functools.reduce(operator.mul, i)
                               for i in unique_combinations)
    combination_product.sort()

    return combination_product


print(calculate_divisors(12500))
>>> [2, 4, 5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100, 125, 250, 500, 625, 1250, 2500, 3125, 6250]
```

In the context of the above algorithm:

1. Can I shorten `factorize` function? (For example, I couldn’t find a way to turn into a list comprehension. I suspect there should be a shorthand via `functools`or `itertools`.)
2. Is there a more Pythonic implementation of `calculate_divisors` function?

Comment: [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/YkNd_zVPQK4) is an implementation of your function by Tim Peters, the guy that names [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), Python's sorting algorithm. It doesn't get much more Pythonic than that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Lazy generators**

Most often in Python you do not want to build an actual list and return it.

If I want to sum the `divisors` of a number, and there are many, I will waste a lot of space if I put them in a list first.

Also, not creating a list is even shorter, you just give out the elements one by one from the function:

```
def factorize(n):
    for item in primes_list:
        if item > n:
            break
        else:
            while n > 1:
                if n % item == 0:
                    n //= item
                    yield item
                else:
                    break
```

**Reduce nesting**

You got some serious nesting going on, each level of nesting is a level of complexity so getting it a bit down is positive. Luckily if we `break` we do not need an `else`: the code after will not be executed anyway:

```
def factorize(n):
    for item in primes_list:
        if item > n:
            break

        while n > 1:
            if n % item != 0:
                break
            n //= item
            yield item
```

Still two nested loops, but the situation is becoming more manageable.

Now let me re-factor the `while` loop away:

```
def how_many_times_divides(n, div):
    """
    >>> list(how_many_times_divides(40, 2))
    [2, 2, 2]
    """
    while n > 1:
        if n % div != 0:
            break
        n //= div
        yield div
```

And now `factorize` is starting to look nice and small:

```
def factorize(n):
    """
    >>> list(factorize(480))
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5]
    """
    for item in primes_list:
        if item > n:
            break
        yield from how_many_times_divides(n, item)
```

**Doctests**

You may have noted that I added some examples of usage in the doc-strings of this functions. They are actually automatically runnable with `doctests` and I highly recommend them when writing numerical code.

**Avoid unnecessary assignments & mutation**

It is just simpler to return the expression:

```
combination_product = list(functools.reduce(operator.mul, i)
                           for i in unique_combinations)
combination_product.sort()

return combination_product
```

Becomes:

```
return sorted(functools.reduce(operator.mul, i)
                 for i in unique_combinations)
```

Note that I omitted `list` as it was not really needed.

Comment: Without generalizing, what is the benefit of yielding prime factors for this case? (I am asking because we need the full list in any case.)

Comment: @blackened the function is also a bit easier to write